# Cordova-plugin-sms too big SMS error

Tags: android, cordova

I´m using Cordova-plugin-sms and it is working fine.
I can send sms except I cant exceed the standart 140-70 characters for each sms.
I need to send 2-in-1 sms like default SMS app.
For the exceeded size sms, it gives a successCallback, but sms is not sent.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms

```
var successCallback = function () {
    msgSentUser(message);
};
var failureCallback = function (e) {
};
SMS.sendSMS(number, fullMsg, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/src/android/SMSPlugin.java) for that plugin, you'll see that it uses the `SmsManager#sendTextMessage()` method - which just fails silently if the message exceeds the character limit - and fires a successful callback, since no Exception is thrown, and no other method of confirmation is used. To do what you want, it would have to utilize the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method.

Comment: That looks promising, how do I do that?

Comment: Gimme a little while, and I'll post the replacement code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I might not been splicit. I need a sms to be sent with all the info, not 2. I´m testing some code right now with sendmultipartextmessage

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am not looking to split the message and send 2 messages. Im trying to send all content in the same SMS like the default sms app do.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/src/android/SMSPlugin.java) for that plugin, you can see that it uses the `SmsManager#sendTextMessage()` method. This method only handles single-part messages, and it will fail silently if you pass it a message that exceeds the character limit for a single part in the alphabet you're using. You still get the `successCallback`, however, since no `Exception` is thrown, and the plugin itself uses no other method of confirmation. The solution is to alter the code to utilize the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method.

In the original source, lines 206 through 212, inclusive, handle the message send, and are what we need to replace. That is, these lines:

```
PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast((Context)this.cordova.getActivity(),
    (int)0, (Intent)new Intent("SENDING_SMS"), (int)0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    String address;
    if ((address = addressList.optString(i)).length() <= 0) continue;
    sms.sendTextMessage(address, null, text, sentIntent, (PendingIntent)null);
}
```

The following replacement block divides the message into the appropriate parts, and creates the necessary `ArrayList` of `PendingIntent`s to pass to the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method. Please note that if you are handling the `SENDING_SMS` broadcast, it will now fire once for each message part, instead of once per send, as it did for single-part messages.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(text);
final int count = parts.size();
ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPIs = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(count);

int req = 0;
PendingIntent pi = null;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String address;
    if ((address = addressList.optString(i)).length() <= 0) continue;

    sentPIs.clear();

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        req = i * count + j;
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast((Context) this.cordova.getActivity(),
            req, new Intent("SENDING_SMS"), 0);

        sentPIs.add(pi);
    }

    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, parts, sentPIs, null);
}
```

---

The incoming message handling in that plugin is not correct, and will result in multipart messages appearing as multiple, separate messages. Two code sections will need to be altered to fix this. The first is lines 350 to 354, inclusive:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; ++i) {
    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])((byte[])pdus[i]));
    JSONObject json = SMSPlugin.this.getJsonFromSmsMessage(sms);
    SMSPlugin.this.onSMSArrive(json);
}
```

Which we change to:

```
JSONObject json = SMSPlugin.this.getJsonFromSmsMessage(pdus);
SMSPlugin.this.onSMSArrive(json);
```

Next, we need to alter the `getJsonFromSmsMessage()` method; lines 447 through 466, inclusive:

```
private JSONObject getJsonFromSmsMessage(SmsMessage sms) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
        json.put( BODY, sms.getMessageBody() );
        json.put( DATE_SENT, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
        json.put( DATE, System.currentTimeMillis() );
        json.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
        json.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );
        json.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
        json.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
        json.put( SERVICE_CENTER, sms.getServiceCenterAddress());

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

This method will now be as follows. Please note that the method's parameter type has changed, and the `JSONObject`'s value for the `BODY` key has, as well.

```
private JSONObject getJsonFromSmsMessage(Object[] pdus) {
    SmsMessage sms = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        sb.append(sms.getMessageBody());
    }

    try {
        json.put(ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress());
        json.put(BODY, sb.toString());
        json.put(DATE_SENT, sms.getTimestampMillis());
        json.put(DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
        json.put(READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ);
        json.put(SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN);
        json.put(STATUS, sms.getStatus());
        json.put(TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX);
        json.put(SERVICE_CENTER, sms.getServiceCenterAddress());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: I´m giving it a try, it´s my first time in stackoverflow, I really apretiate your time and efford.

Comment: Seems like the sendMultipartTextMessage() method works. But it has the same result, im sending a sms with GIS information + text, if i use special characters it turns into UTF16 and can only write 70chars, that's my problem , i´m only allowed to enter 10 characters for user message if it has special characters, the message will have to be send together.

Comment: TESTING..........I´ll tell you what is happening and what I´m expecting. I´m making a chat inApp, the App user will send an Iden GIS code + his message, and it has to be sent in 1 message ( wich is my problem right now). And yes you are right, if the App user receives an SMS the message will be split in 3-4 messages, but if I refresh the chatbox it will add the 3-4messages + the complete text one

Comment: The result its oddly the same. I receive 3 sms, but when I refresh the page, I get another one that Is the concat of those 3 ( what I was expecting). BTW what minimum, recommended should I use as SDK?

Comment: What I can do: (its kinda bad but it should work) since im receiving all the messages inapp currectly but separated, I can set a timer after an sms is received and concat with every message sent in those 100ms or something.

Comment: i solved the sms concat with that post up there. Thank you. But what i really need is to be able to send multi-part-sms, wich is not working

Comment: sendMultipartTextMessage was acting like sendTextMessage, was not working properly. I found out that ArrayList was not imported, so im testing it.

Comment: the result is still the same. imported arraylist & stringbuilder. nothing happened

Comment: i´ll add a link then

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/TH4rG/cordova-plugin-sms.zip                                                                                                                  I´m very glad you are willing to help

Comment: im just using this plugin to send multi and to receive concat messages. I just took the plugin owner suggestions, if you think you can give me a better idea feel free.

Comment: BTW, that index.html test IS NOT MY CODE! im simply doing:                   var successCallback = function () {
        msgSentUser(message);
        addConversationMessage(message, "user");
        document.getElementById("messageTxtSend").value = "";
    };
    var failureCallback = function (e) {
    };
    SMS.sendSMS(number, fullMsg, successCallback, failureCallback);

Comment: sry I did not notice that code was there...ignore that.

Comment: TY for your suggestion. I will try that right now. I will contact when I find whats going on with this plugin.

Comment: the problem is that  I cannot call the sendSms on simulator. Only on phone, and there I see logs

Comment: The problem here is that safesmsexport.sendSMS (on sms.js) send the sms without the need of  PluginResult sendSMS (SMSPlugin.java). All it needs is    : cordova.exec( successCallback, failureCallback, 'SMS', 'sendSMS', [ numbers, text ] );

Comment: With both the plugins I mensioned , im able to do what I want, but I would like to add startWatch to https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin , That all I need, I tried but failed :(

Answer (score 0):

For the sms concat i used this: ( i use this because 1 to 1 chat)

```
var totalSms = "";
function timeToAdd(newSms) {
        totalSms = totalSms + newSms;
        if (totalSms == newSms) {      // only waits the first time
            window.setTimeout(
                function () {                 
                    msgReceived(totalSms);
                    addConversationMessage(totalSms, "sender");
                    totalSms = "";
                }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

it basicly waits 1 second after the first "onsmsarrive" event to concat all the sms received (since every sms takes >1s to send) it should work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is in:

```
safesmsExport.sendSMS = function(address, text, successCallback, failureCallback) {

    var numbers;
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( address ) === '[object Array]' ) {
        numbers = address;
    } else if(typeof address === 'string') {
        numbers = [ address ];
    } else {
        if(typeof failureCallback === 'function') {
            failureCallback("require address, phone number as string, or array of string");
        }
        return;
    }

    cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SMS', 'sendSMS', [numbers, text]);

};
```

This is not calling the function sendSMS from the smsPlugin.java. Stands alone on SMS send even if smsPlugin sendSMS is commented.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to change plugin. I got this one to work sending big sms: https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin , the problem is that this one doesn't have the startwatch. im trying to add it ( I'm new on plugins and JS as you can see)